# How to add container to a frame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am trying to make a minesweeper that has a different space for a smiley icon that we can click and the buttons which we have to click to play.

```
public final class testFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener, ActionListener {

private JFrame screen = null;
private JPanel composite = new JPanel();
public testFrame() {
    screen = new JFrame();
    screen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    screen.setVisible(true);
    screen.setResizable(true);
    composite.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //this button is not showing also
    JButton button = new JButton("Text goes here");
    composite.add(button);

    Container cp = screen.getContentPane();           // JFrame's content-pane
    cp.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5, 2, 2)); // in 10x10 GridLayout
    //codes to add buttons
 }
```

So here I am trying to add the container cp to the screen. But it opened
[two screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcCnp.png)

Sorry if this seems like minor things but I am really new to this java GUI so please help me.

EDIT:
I removed the extends JFrame and used the screen instead. It kinda works but I can't seem to put the container cp to a panel. The requirement is that I have to use container cp. So I cannot change. Thank you

```
public final class TestFrame implements MouseListener, ActionListener {
 private JFrame screen = null;
 private JPanel composite = new JPanel();
 private JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
 public TestFrame() {
    screen = new JFrame("TestFrame");
    screen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    screen.setVisible(true);
    topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //composite.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //button in topPanel
    JButton button = new JButton("Text goes here");
    topPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    //Content Pane
    Container cp = screen.getContentPane();// JFrame's content-pane
    cp.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5, 2, 2)); // in 10x10 GridLayout

    //composite.add(cp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    screen.add(topPanel);
    // screen.add(composite);
 }
```

Now it looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSjfs.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things.

1. You are extending JFrame as well as using it as an attribute of the same class so you can ether use `this` instead of `screen` or you remove the `extends JFrame` as it is redundant and not needed
2. To answer your question. A JFrame contains a Panel called `ContentPane` this pane is were you add you panels to (you already did the layout thing right). So the solution is:

```java
cp.add(composite);
```

Comment: Hi, I remove the extends JFrame and use the screen variable instead. I added a new Panel for the smiley icon so currently, i have topPanel and composite. the cp.add(composite) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You've got too many JFrames, the `testFrame` class which extends JFrame (and which should be re-named `TestFrame` to comply with Java naming conventions) and the screen variable. Use only one.

You can and should nest JPanels to achieve your desired result. For instance if you want a grid as well as some control buttons, create a JPanel, give it a BorderLayout, put your grid JPanel in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` postion and a JPanel with control JButtons in a different position, say `BorderLayout.PAGE_START`

Comment: Hi, I remove the extends JFrame and use the screen variable instead. I tried to put the Container cp inside the composite but it doesn't work.